# UNION of tables with different columns without specifying them, or coalesced FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have a set of tables which have many different columns (such that listing them manually in `SELECT` clause would be a bad thing).

I would like to combine them together similar to a `UNION` result, except UNION requires the columns in all of the tables match exactly (if they don't, you have to add dummy NULL values).

So:

```
Table1
Domain   | Field1 | Field2 | etc
foo.com    1        2        
bar.com    0        1        

Table2
Domain   | FieldX | FieldY | etc
foo.com     3        9        
baz.com    10       11        

Table3
Domain   | FieldA | FieldB | etc
baz.com    1        2        
qux.com    123      56
```

Desired result:

```
Domain | Field1 | Field2 | ... | FieldX | FieldY | ... | FieldA | FieldB | ...
foo.com  1        2               3        9
bar.com  0        1
baz.com                          10       11               1       2
qux.com                                                  123      56
```

I tried using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as an alternative, but it gives me excess data due to it being an OUTER join.

Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3fa84/2

Comment: What is "excess data"?

Comment: @SkinnyJ Rows with a non-distinct `Domain` column value, for example in the SQLFiddle example, `reddit.com` appears twice, with non-coalesced field values.

Comment: Yes, you have `null` values present, but that's nearly mandatory when having different columns.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to generate the union statement. You can right click a table and `Script As -> Select` to get a column list. Or you can use the sys.columns view to generate a SQL string.

Comment: You could rename the `domain` columns for all the tables in outer join with `as` (except one) and ignore those columns in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

At first make a list of all distinct Domains using `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) (here it is assumed that in each of the tables Domain is unique) and then `LEFT JOIN` all your tables to it.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( [Domain] varchar(50), X1 int, X2 int );
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ( [Domain] varchar(50), Y1 int, Y2 int );
DECLARE @Table3 TABLE ( [Domain] varchar(50), Z1 int, Z2 int );

INSERT INTO @Table1 ( [Domain], X1, X2 ) VALUES
( 'Foo.com', 1, 2 ),
( 'Bar.com', 0, 1 );

INSERT INTO @Table2 ( [Domain], Y1, Y2 ) VALUES
( 'Blah.com', 3, 0 ),
( 'Bar.com', 2, 1 ),
( 'reddit.com', -1, -2 );

INSERT INTO @Table3 ( [Domain], Z1, Z2 ) VALUES
( 'Gggg.com', 22, 33 ),
( 'Foo.com', 22, 44 ),
( 'bar.com', 50, 51 ),
( 'reddit.com', 10, 20 );

WITH
CTE_Domains
AS
(
    SELECT Domain FROM @Table1
    UNION
    SELECT Domain FROM @Table2
    UNION
    SELECT Domain FROM @Table3
)
SELECT
    CTE_Domains.Domain
    ,X1
    ,X2
    ,Y1
    ,Y2
    ,Z1
    ,Z2
FROM
    CTE_Domains
    LEFT JOIN @Table1 AS T1 ON T1.Domain = CTE_Domains.Domain
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 AS T2 ON T2.Domain = CTE_Domains.Domain
    LEFT JOIN @Table3 AS T3 ON T3.Domain = CTE_Domains.Domain
ORDER BY CTE_Domains.Domain;
```

This is the result set:

```
Domain        X1      X2      Y1      Y2      Z1      Z2
Bar.com       0       1       2       1       50      51
Blah.com      NULL    NULL    3       0       NULL    NULL
Foo.com       1       2       NULL    NULL    22      44
Gggg.com      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22      33
reddit.com    NULL    NULL    -1      -2      10      20
```

If you write `SELECT *` instead of explicit list of columns, the result set would be this. The `Domain` column is repeated for each joined table.

```
Domain        Domain     X1      X2      Domain        Y1      Y2      Domain        Z1      Z2
Bar.com       Bar.com    0       1       Bar.com       2       1       bar.com       50      51
Blah.com      NULL       NULL    NULL    Blah.com      3       0       NULL          NULL    NULL
Foo.com       Foo.com    1       2       NULL          NULL    NULL    Foo.com       22      44
Gggg.com      NULL       NULL    NULL    NULL          NULL    NULL    Gggg.com      22      33
reddit.com    NULL       NULL    NULL    reddit.com    -1      -2      reddit.com    10      20
```

Comment: The problem is that you still need to manually specify the columns, unless would it work with `SELECT CTE_Domains.Domain, *` instead?

Comment: @Dai You can write `SELECT *`. The result set would have the `Domain` column included several times. See the updated answer. Usually it is better to list all your columns explicitly, rather than use `*`. I don't think it is possible to "include all columns, except one".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you what you want with no excess rows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t3.Domain, t1t2.Domain) AS Domain,    
       t1t2.X1, t1t2.X2, t1t2.Y1, t1t2.Y2,
       t3.Z1, t3.Z2
FROM Table3 AS t3
FULL OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT COALESCE(t1.Domain, t2.Domain) AS Domain, t1.X1, t1.X2, t2.Y1, t2.Y2
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Domain = t2.Domain ) AS t1t2
      ON t3.Domain = t1t2.Domain
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3fa84)